# Android in-app update dialog with custom layout

Tags: android, in-app-update

I want to use the in-app update API but with a custom layout, not the default one shown in [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates)

Comment: You need to create a custom dialog of your design. In the launch activity of you app you need to call an api or request to your local database to get the version of the app. Compare the versions to show/hide dialog for you update.

Comment: @SaugatJonchhen I want to use the functionality of the new in-app update API with my custom layout